# CURL server script not getting post values

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using php and CURL for my application. I push few details to server using curl post method.I post json string to server.This json string contains values like 
`"state":"jammu & Kashmir"` but when i try to collect data using `$_POST` in server it breaks at `"state":"jammu` and server does not get full json string.How do i solve this problem. Which function should i use. Should i use urlencode on client side and urldecode on server side.

```
function index()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        $post = array('id'=>'11','name'=>'jammu & kashmir','active'=>4);

        $post = json_encode($post);
        $formatorder        =   "string=".$post;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $formatorder);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/rest/index.php/api/example/user"); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        print_r(curl_error($ch));
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($output);
    }
```

Comment: why aren't you send an array and use json_encode in the web?

Comment: i build a array of key and values and the use json_encode to convert it into json string and post to url

Comment: So can't you send array and use json_encode in the web ? any problem ?

Comment: @Hacker: Show us your code.

Comment: What is the content type header being used for the request? Is the curl request being made with `application/json` as the content type?

Comment: @Hacker What content type header are you using?  I ask because this is very important to the problem.  The chances are, if you are POSTing a JSON string you SHOULD be using `application\json` as content type and getting the POSTed data from PHP's raw input stream.  It probably makes more sense the sending a form-encoded content type and trying to form a query string (which would need to both be urlencoded and also have a parameter name provided).

Comment: @Hacker: Probably unrelated to the actual issue, but if you're using cURL to POST the JSON, you'd need something like [this](https://eval.in/140391).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an issue with ampersands not being encoded (i.e. the ampersand is being interpreted and breaking when you post the data).

During your post, you need to convert your ampersand correctly (i.e. to something like `%26`).

If you're doing client side posting (via jQuery, AJAX or something similar) see: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Are you suggesting that the OP should `urlencode()` the whole JSON data?

Comment: @Louis - at server end should i use urldecode ?? or is it not mandatory.

Comment: If you encoded the whole thing, then sure. But the gist of the problem is you need to encode the ampersand somehow. I suppose a simple string replacement would suffice, though I imagine PHP has native functions to handle such a thing (I'm a bit rusty in my PHP).

Answer (score 0):

If you are POSTing only a JSON string, you should probably set your Content-Type header for the request to be `application/json` and then read the data from PHP raw input.  `$_POST` is only populatedfor form-encoded content types and expects a properly formed query string to be passed in order for the `$_POST` array to be built.

Reading from PHP raw input is simple. It would look like this:

```
// get JSON string from raw input
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// decode the JSON string to a usable data structure
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Taking this approach avoids the need to url-encode the data and build a query string.  The problem you are currently having is that when you POST something like

```
{"state":"jammu & Kashmir"}
```

without using `application/json` content type, PHP assumes that `&` is the parameter delimiter for a query string.  To use a query string and `$_POST` you would need to form your query string like:

```
json=[URL-encoded JSON string]
```

And then get the POSTed data in `$_POST['json']`.